# Windivert fails in Win10 - Solution to TCP 3handshake - Evade windows RST packets

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, driver

I had a project which used windivert to work as a router in my network, and it worked fine but now is dead with the same code. Previous versions which worked succesfully now dont work. I always get the same Windivert error which is 997 (Overlapped I/O operation is in progress).

For example when I use WindivertOpen I get the error, when I restart the computer to reset the windivert driver I dont get the error 997 in WindivertOpen but I get it in WindivertSend or WinDivertSendEx and after use them I again get the error in WindivertOpen. These functions worked fine for me months ago and my router worked as I expected, but now I am done with these errors, there is nothing I can do, maybe this is caused by a windows security update.

I need to know how to reset the driver without restart the computer and to know what I can do to face this problem. I used windivert to block windows TCP RST packets to my router fordwards, windows does this when there is not sockets associated with the ports that you are fordwarding, what can I do to block this packets without windivert or with a working way of windivert?

Answer (score 0):

The 997 error is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, but the error code is meaningless unless `WinDivertOpen` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.  Otherwise the call will have completed successfully.

Presumably you have upgraded to WinDivert 1.4 from a previous version.  Simply replacing the binary files (`dll`/`sys`) won't work -- you must instead recompile your program against the new API.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Basil, I solved the problem and now Windivert works again, I was using the dll, lib, and driver incorrectly. Please check my new issue maybe you can help me, im really gratefull to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883790/windivert-does-not-block-windows-rst